# Catch SIGINT in Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: c++, xcode, signals, sigint

In Xcode, I want to do something when ctrl + c is pressed, but it looks like lldb doesn't catch SIGINT signal. I tried the most simple C++ program, just for a test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
  
void sigintHandler(int sig_num)
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    printf("I'm doing something \n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
  
int main ()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
  
    while(1)
    {        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it won't work. I also tried the solution:

```
process handle SIGINT -s false
process handle SIGINT -p true
```

Still, it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want sigint to stop, use -s true (stop=true) and -p false (pass=false) -> the program continue running after, but pauses when it receives the sigint. -s false (stop=false) and -p true (pass=true) will make the sigint to behave as it should, stopping the application.

Comment: There is no need to call `signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);` again in your signal handler

Answer (score 0):

In the modern versions of XCode it is hard to intercept SIGINT. For debug purposes it is better to use SIGINFO in place of SIGINT. You can generate that in Terminal using ^T (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

So during debugging temporary replace SIGINT with SIGINFO in your code. To intercept SIGINFO try next steps all together:

1. Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Options and change Console from Use Xcode to Use Terminal.
2. Run your program
3. Pause the program
4. In the Xcode console, enter this:

```
(lldb) process handle -p true -s false -n false SIGINFO
```

You will get:

```
NAME         PASS   STOP   NOTIFY
===========  =====  =====  ======
SIGINFO      true   false  false
```

5. Resume the program
6. Switch to Terminal and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Your signal handler will fire.

Don't forget to return SIGINT back after finishing debugging!